# How do you draw a figure like this using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]I have to include this picture in my slides that I teach to my students. Can someone help me in drawing this picture using tikz package. Thanks

Comment: look I am new to this latex thing, and I haven't actually tried anything. I don't know how to work with figures. Thought maybe someone would write the code

Comment: How would you feel if your students posted a question from your class on a website without showing any effort whatsoever?

Comment: Wasn't your question phrased differently originally? It seemed to me when I read it that you had tried, but failed. That said, I think you can get a long way in making this if you go through the first tutorial in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (i.e. chapter 2, *Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students*).